# pgfplotstable wrong cell alignment

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, pgfplotstable

The cells and headers in my table are wrongly aligned: the headers are not set left and the last column reaches over the horizontal lines.

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable} 
    \pgfplotstableset{
        font=\small,
        begin table=\begin{longtable},
        end table=\end{longtable},
        col sep=semicolon,
        read comma as period=true,
        every column/.style={column type=l, fixed, fixed zerofill},
        every first column/.style={column type/.add={@{}}{}},
        every last column/.style={column type/.add={}{@{}}},
        empty header/.style={every head row/.style={output empty row}}
    }
    
    \begin{filecontents*}{test.CSV}
        Quadrant;Bereich;Nummer;Ra 1;Ra 2;Ra 3;Ra_m;Ra_s;Rz 1;Rz 2;Rz 3;Rz_m;Rz_s;Rz_m_B;Rz_s_B;Rz_m_Q;Rz_s_Q;E-Modul;Bruchdehnung;Zugfestigkeit;Streckdehnung
        0;0;1;14,030;13,770;13,850;13,883;0,109;68,8;67,4;67,5;67,90;0,64;51,50;10,55;51,50;10,55;;;;
        0;0;2;8,526;8,583;8,554;8,554;0,023;43,1;44,5;44,9;44,17;0,77;;;;;;;;
        0;0;3;8,911;9,284;8,631;8,942;0,267;43,0;48,1;41,8;44,30;2,73;;;;;;;;
        0;0;4;12,560;12,460;12,330;12,450;0,094;65,2;63,3;61,8;63,43;1,39;;;;;;;;
        0;0;5;10,270;9,569;9,536;9,792;0,339;52,3;48,3;49,0;49,87;1,74;;;;;;;;
        0;0;6;7,770;7,387;7,366;7,508;0,186;40,8;39,2;38,0;39,33;1,15;;;;;;;;
        I;i;1;8,545;8,395;8,467;8,469;0,061;44,4;44,3;44,3;44,33;0,05;50,55;8,32;54,24;9,43;;;;
    \end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
        columns={Quadrant, Bereich, Nummer, Rz 1, Rz 2, Rz 3, Rz_m, Rz_s},
        columns/Quadrant/.style={string type, column type=l},
        columns/Bereich/.style={string type, column type=l},
        columns/Nummer/.style={string type, column type=l},
        columns/Rz 1/.style={precision=1},
        columns/Rz 2/.style={precision=1},
        columns/Rz 3/.style={precision=1},
        columns/Rz_m/.style={precision=2},
        columns/Rz_s/.style={precision=2},
        empty header,
        every first row/.append style={%
            before row={%
                \caption{Messergebnisse der Oberflächenuntersuchung der Zugstäbe}\label{tab:rauheit_mess} \\
                \toprule
                \multicolumn{3}{@{}c}{Zugstab} & \multicolumn{5}{c@{}}{Oberflächenrauheit $R_{z}$ in \si{\um}} \\
                \cmidrule(r){1-3} \cmidrule(l){4-8}
                Quadrant & Bereich & Nummer & \#1 & \#2 & \#3 & $\overline{x}$ & $\sigma$ \\
                \midrule
                \endfirsthead
                %
                \multicolumn{8}{@{}l}{{\textsc{tabelle}\ \thetable{} -- Fortsetzung}} \\
                \toprule 
                %
                \multicolumn{3}{@{}c}{Zugstab} & \multicolumn{5}{c@{}}{Oberflächenrauheit $R_{z}$ in \si{\um}} \\
                \cmidrule(r){1-3} \cmidrule(l){4-8}
                Quadrant & Bereich & Nummer & \#1 & \#2 & \#3 & $\overline{x}$ & $\sigma$ \\
                \midrule
                \endhead
                %
                \bottomrule
                \multicolumn{8}{r@{}}{Fortsetzung auf nächster Seite}
                \endfoot
                %
                \bottomrule
                \endlastfoot
            }
        }
    ]{test.CSV}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT:** The problem with the overreaching last column is apparently due to longtable and its columnwidths. Compiling it three times resolves the issue. The problem with the first column still remains however.

Comment: If I compile your example code 3 times (until the `longtable` waring "Column widths have changed" is no longer present), I get the following output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMV5g.png. I can't see the misalignment of "Quadrant" with respect to the numbers there.

Comment: As leandriis points out, you only need to compile 3 times for the alignment to be correct.

Comment: @leandriis mit with respect to the numbers, but @{} should remove the whitespace in the first column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what caused the white space in the first column. I specified the column type twice, which leads to the white space. Deleting one solves the issue.